# Finding value of a quadratic

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial 
\begin{equation*}
p(x)= ax^2+bx+c 
\end{equation*}
has $1+\sqrt{3}$ as one of it's roots and also $p(2)=-2$. Is there any way to know the value of $a$, $b$ and $c$? I tried but I can form only $2$ equations how can I figure out value of $3$ unknown with $2$ equations so something must be missing.

Also $a$, $b$ and $c$ are rationals.

Comment: Are we given any additional information about $a, b, c$?

Comment: a,b,c are rational

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If one of the roots is $1 + \sqrt{3}$ and $a, b, c$ are rational then what must the other root be?

---

**Solution 1**:

The other root must then be $1 - \sqrt{3}$.

You have two options now: You can make a system of three linear equations in three variables and simply solve.

Or, you can simply expand $\alpha[x - (1 - \sqrt{3})][x - (1 + \sqrt{3})] = \alpha(x^2 - 2x - 2)$ and use $p(2) = -2$ to get $\alpha = 1$.

---

**Solution 2**:

We only need two equations if we know that $a, b, c$ are rational.

$$(1+\sqrt{3})^2 a + (1+\sqrt{3})b + c = 0$$

$$4a + 2\sqrt{3} a + b + \sqrt{3} b + c = 0$$

$a, b, c$ are rational, so we know that $-2a = b$ because the $\sqrt{3}$ terms must cancel each other.
So, $4a + 2b + c = -2$ gives us $c = -2$.

Substituting back into the above we get $4a + b = 2$, so $a = 1$ and $b = -2$.

Thus the quadratic is $x^2 - 2x - 2$.

Comment: +1 for the hint. You could say $p(x)=\alpha (x-x_1)(x-x_2)=\alpha (x^2-2x-2)$ and use $p(2)=-2$ to conclude $\alpha=1$.

Comment: @mhp Right, forgot about the $p(2)= -2$ condition to get the lead coefficient

Answer (score 0):

$$p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
given that $x=1+\sqrt 3$ so there must me an $x=1- \sqrt 3$ as in a quadratic polynomial when you get the roots the irrational part is from the discriminant as $a,b,c$ are rational.
$$p(x)=(x-(1+\sqrt 3))(x-(1- \sqrt 3))$$
expanding this we get,
$$p(x)=x^2-2x-2$$

Comment: I believe you mean discriminant rather than determinant, also you said $1+\sqrt{3}$ twice. Perhaps you meant $1-\sqrt{3}$ the second time?

Comment: ya discrimi.. that thing and thanks for pointing the type error

Answer (score -1):

Let $x = 1+\sqrt{3} \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 = 3 \Rightarrow x^2-2x-2 = 0 \Rightarrow a = k, b = -2k,c = -2k$, and $p(2) = -2 \Rightarrow 4a+2b+c=-2\Rightarrow 4k - 4k - 2k = -2 \Rightarrow k = 1 \Rightarrow (a,b,c) = (1,-2,-2)$.

Comment: Does this implicitly use the fact that $a, b, c$ are rational anywhere?

Comment: I am struggling to see how only the fact that $p(2) = -2$ and $1 + \sqrt{3}$ is a root, with all coefficients in the reals, gives us a unique quadratic. Why can't we construct many such quadratics with that property?

Comment: We can, we only have two points. For any three points (with distinct $x$ values), there is a unique quadratic through those points by Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @jgon Which is why ask how NotALoner gets a unique solution with only two points

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  If you do not use the fact that the coefficients are rational, you could equally well say$$x=1+\sqrt3\quad\Rightarrow\quad(x-1-\sqrt3)(x+1)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad x^2-\sqrt3x-1-\sqrt3=0$$and so$$(a,b,c)=k(1,-\sqrt3,-1-\sqrt3)\ .$$

Comment: You're tacitly assuming that $x^2-2x-2$ is the minimal polynomial for $1+\sqrt{3}$, so that it divides $ax^2+bx+c$, so that $a=k$, $b=-2k$, and $c=-2k$. This is true over $\Bbb{Q}$ not $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @David I thought something fishy was at play here.

Comment: @Soke Your hint is correct, I have upvoted it.